# Cannot get page to redirect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and Dropzone.js to drag and drop files and upload them on form submission. I don't know why I can't get this to work but I'm trying to redirect after the form submits to a certain page but its not doing it (everything saves correctly though).

Here is my code:

> items/new.html.haml > _form.html.haml

```
= form_for @item, validate: true, 
  html: {id: 'item-form', class: 'form-horizontal form', multipart: true} do |f|

    = f.text_field :name

    %main#image-preview
        #dropzone
            .fallback
                = f.file_field :image, multiple: false

    = f.submit 'Done', id: 'item-submit'
```

> items.coffee

```
  Dropzone.autoDiscover = false

  if document.getElementById('item-form')
    dropzone = new Dropzone('#item-form',
      maxFiles: 1
      maxFilesize: 1
      paramName: 'item[image]'
      headers: "X-CSRF-Token" : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      addRemoveLinks: true
      clickable: '#image-preview'
      previewsContainer: '#image-preview'
      thumbnailWidth: 200
      thumbnailHeight: 200
      autoProcessQueue: false
      uploadMultiple: false)

    $('#item-submit').on 'click', (e) ->
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      if dropzone.getQueuedFiles().length > 0
        dropzone.processQueue()
      else
        $getScript '/items'
      return
```

> items_controller.rb

```
  def continue
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    if @item.user_id == current_user.id
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.xml
        format.json { render :json => {} }
      end
    end
  end

  def new
    @item = current_user.items.build
  end

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.json { render :json => "window.location = #{post_continue_item_path(@item).to_json}" }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

> routes.rb

```
resources :items do
  get '/post/continue', to: 'items#continue', on: :member
end
```

> log

```
Started POST "/items" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-06 12:23:35 -0700
Processing by ItemsController#create as JSON
............
Completed 200 OK in 1786ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 10.6ms)
```

Not sure where to go with this so how do I redirect when its giving me a JSON call?

Answer (score 0):

JSON is not Javascript. It is designed to pass some data, not a working code. Check the response with your browser's developer tools, you will see your 'window.location' script nicely wrapped and basically unable to do anything - it should come as a mere string.

If you want a pure, classical HTTP redirect, you should look into `redirect_to` Rails method as your only response, and never try to render a JSON when you actually need a redirect.